# struts 1.3, find action in post filter/ jsp

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts-1

Is there a way to know the final struts forward that rendered a tiles page?

Example we do

```
return mapping.findForward("/checkout/shipping");
```

Want the string "/checkout/shipping" in my j2ee filter or in my jsp.

Comment: You could probably do something with a custom request processor and/or a mapping class wrapper to grab the strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
public class YourCustomeFilter implements Filter {
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
           HttpServletResponse reponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;

           //your url validation goes here

            chain.doFilter(req, res);        
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a shell filter, how does this give me the action name?

Comment: String yourControllerDo = request.getContextPath() + "/yourcontroller_url.do";

Comment: i think your close but the question is to get the url after processing. anyway i sovled it with my own custom filter, the code goes after the doFilter ...